# my mobile website is loading inconsistently on iphone

Tags: html, css, mobile, scroll, overflow

I am working on a mobile website template and I'm not sure the reason why sometimes it loads properly on my iphone and other times it only loads the body (a blank background with the navy color i set the body to). Some of the alerts I have in my code come up as expected but the rest of the containers and header doesn't load at all sometimes however sometimes it loads perfectly without having change any code. it is inconsistent so hard to figure out. But it always loads on my desktop without errors.
A bit about my code:
I load in a css file which is served to all devices. In this file the header is position absolute and there is no set height on the container_wrapper or the body.
In a js file I call a method which checks if the browser supports overflow: scroll. 
IF it does support, then the document alerts true (just for debugging at the moment). the alerts are coming up perfectly correct for different phones.
If it does support overflow scroll i then call a method which adds some extra css styling i.e a height to the body and container_wrapper and sets the header to fixed position.. There is also a class called scrollable which enables scrolling (with css styling)to the container div and the side menu div. I would be grateful if anyone has any ideas on why it would load inconsistently. I have attached 3 images. first one of the blank page when it hasnt loaded properly and the second two of when it loads properly.

thank you...

heres my css.

```
body{
margin-top: 0px;  
font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
width: 100%;
overflow: auto;
background: #120F3A;
}


#container_wrapper{
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 100%;
background: #120F3A;
overflow: auto;
max-width: 100%; 
z-index: 2;
-webkit-transition: .3s;
-moz-transition: .3s;
-o-transition: .3s;
transition: .3s;  
}


#container{
position: relative; 
overflow: hidden;
z-index: 2;
}


/********************************************/
/*Styling for header and drop down menu. Used on every page */
header{
width: 100%;
}

header nav{
width: 100%;
}
#headernav {  
width: 100%;  
position:absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
z-index: 10;
background: #000;
padding-bottom: 2px;
-webkit-transition: .3s; /* Safari */
transition: .3s;
}


#swipe_menu_right{
display: block;
width: 80%;
max-width: 80%;
position:absolute;
background: #120F3A;
top: 0px;
left: 20%;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
z-index:1;
overflow: auto;
-webkit-transition: .3s; 
-moz-transition: .3s;
-o-transition: .3s;
transition: .3s;  
}

#header_right{
display: none;
z-index: 600;
width: 25%;
position: fixed;
overflow: hidden;
left: -5%;

}

.scrollable{
overflow: scroll;
-webkit-transition-property: top, bottom;
-moz-transition-property: top, bottom;
-o-transition-property: top, bottom;
transition-property: top, bottom;

-webkit-transition-duration: .2s, .2s;
-moz-transition-duration: .2s, .2s;
-o-transition-duration: .2s, .2s;
transition-duration: .2s, .2s;

-webkit-transition-timing-function: linear, linear;
-moz-transition-timing-function: linear, linear;
-o-transition-timing-function: linear, linear;
transition-timing-function: linear, linear;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

#menu_list{
position: relative; 
overflow: hidden;

}
#menu_list .accordian_nav{
margin-top: 0px;
padding-top: 0px;
}
#menu_list .accordian_nav ul{
width: 94%;
margin-left: 6%;

}
#menu_list .menu_level_1{
width: 95%;
margin: 0px 0% 0px 0%;
border: none;
-webkit-border-radius: 0px;
-moz-border-radius: 0px;
-o-border-radius: 0px;
border-radius: 0px;
}
```

and a Js file called js_functions which I load in after the css is loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    try{
    if((sessionStorage.getItem("canScroll") != 'false') && (sessionStorage.getItem("canScroll") != 'true')){
        if(canOverflowScroll()){
            alert('true');
            changeCssOnDocReady();
            sessionStorage.setItem("canScroll", "true");    
        }else{
            alert('false');
            sessionStorage.setItem("canScroll", "false");   
        }
    }else if(sessionStorage.getItem("canScroll") == 'true'){
        changeCssOnDocReady();
    }

    }catch(error){
            alert(error.message);
    }
});

function changeCssOnDocReady(){
    alert(' csstrue');
    $('body').css({
        'height': '100%'
    });
    $('#container_wrapper').css({
        'height': '100%'
    });
    $('#swipe_menu_right').css({
        'height': '100%'
    });
    $("#headernav").css({
        'position': 'fixed'
    });
    alert('wrapper height' + $('#container_wrapper').height());
}
function canOverflowScroll() {
    return (
        // Features-first. iOS5 overflow scrolling property check - no UA needed here. thanks Apple :)
        "WebkitOverflowScrolling" in window.document.documentElement.style ||
        // Touch events aren't supported and screen width is greater than X
        // ...basically, this is a loose "desktop browser" check. 
        // It may wrongly opt-in very large tablets with no touch support.
        window.screen.width > 1200 ||
        // Hang on to your hats.
        // Whitelist some popular, overflow-supporting mobile browsers for now and the future
        // These browsers are known to get overlow support right, but give us no way of detecting it.
        (function() {
            var ua = window.navigator.userAgent,
                // Webkit crosses platforms, and the browsers on our list run at least version 534
                webkit = ua.match(/AppleWebKit\/([0-9]+)/),
                wkversion = webkit && webkit[1],
                wkLte534 = webkit && wkversion >= 534;

            return (
                /* Android 3+ with webkit gte 534
                ~: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 3.0; en-us; Xoom Build/HRI39) AppleWebKit/534.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Safari/534.13 */
                ua.match(/Android ([0-9]+)/) && RegExp.$1 >= 3 && wkLte534 ||
                /* Windows Phone 
                ~: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows Phone 8.0; Trident/6.0; IEMobile/10.0; ARM; Touch; NOKIA; Lumia 920) */
                ua.match(/IEMobile\/(\d\d).\d+/) && RegExp.$1 >= 10 ||
                /* Blackberry 7+ with webkit gte 534
                ~: Mozilla/5.0 (BlackBerry; U; BlackBerry 9900; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.11+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.0 Mobile Safari/534.11+ */
                ua.match(/ Version\/([0-9]+)/) && RegExp.$1 >= 0 && window.blackberry && wkLte534 ||
                /* Blackberry Playbook with webkit gte 534
                ~: Mozilla/5.0 (PlayBook; U; RIM Tablet OS 1.0.0; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.8+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/0.0.1 Safari/534.8+ */
                ua.indexOf(/PlayBook/) > -1 && RegExp.$1 >= 0 && wkLte534 ||
                /* Firefox Mobile (Fennec) 4 and up
                ~: Mozilla/5.0 (Mobile; rv:15.0) Gecko/15.0 Firefox/15.0 */
                ua.match(/Firefox\/([0-9]+)/) && RegExp.$1 >= 4 ||
                /* WebOS 3 and up (TouchPad too)
                ~: Mozilla/5.0 (hp-tablet; Linux; hpwOS/3.0.0; U; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.6 (KHTML, like Gecko) wOSBrowser/233.48 Safari/534.6 TouchPad/1.0 */
                ua.match(/wOSBrowser\/([0-9]+)/) && RegExp.$1 >= 233 && wkLte534 ||
                /* Nokia Browser N8
                ~: Mozilla/5.0 (Symbian/3; Series60/5.2 NokiaN8-00/012.002; Profile/MIDP-2.1 Configuration/CLDC-1.1 ) AppleWebKit/533.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) NokiaBrowser/7.3.0 Mobile Safari/533.4 3gpp-gba 
                ~: Note: the N9 doesn't have native overflow with one-finger touch. wtf */
                ua.match(/NokiaBrowser\/([0-9\.]+)/) && parseFloat(RegExp.$1) === 7.3 && webkit && wkversion >= 533
            );
        })()
    );
}
```

my html code:

```
<body ontouchstart="">
    <div id="header_right">
        <span class="more_button_swipe"><i class="fa fa-navicon"></i></span>
    </div>
    <div id="swipe_menu_right" class="scrollable">  
        <div id="menu_list">
            <div class="header_side_menu"><h3>Menu</h3></div>
            <ul class="accordian_nav">
                <li><span class="menu_level_1 block"><i class="fa fa-headphones icon_width"></i>Audio<i class="fa fa-plus-square plus_minus_arrow"></i></span>      
                            <ul>        
                                    <li><a class="menu_level_2 ableton_music_link" href="music-production.php#">Music Production<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a></li>
                                    <li><a class="menu_level_2 dj_techniques_link" href="techniques.php">Techniques Cert.<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a></li>
                                    <li><a class="menu_level_2" href="#">DJ Techniques Cert.<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a></li>        
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                <li><span class="menu_level_1 block"><i class="fa fa-gamepad icon_width"></i>Games<i class="fa fa-plus-square plus_minus_arrow"></i></span>
                    <ul>
                                    <li><a class="menu_level_2" href="music-production.php#">3D Game<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a></li>
                            </ul>

                </li>
                <li><span class="menu_level_1 block"><i class="fa fa-laptop icon_width"></i>I.T.<i class="fa fa-plus-square plus_minus_arrow"></i></span>
                    <ul>
                                    <li><a class="menu_level_2" href="music-production.php#">D Programming<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a></li>
                                    <li><a class="menu_level_2" href="music-production.php#">D C Proamming<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a></li>
                                </ul>   
                </li>
                        <li><a class="menu_level_1 vouchers_link"><i class="fa fa-gift icon_width"></i>Voucher Deals<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a></li>
                <li><a class="menu_level_1 about_link" href="about-us.php#"><i class="fa fa-info-circle icon_width"></i>About Us<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a></li>
                <li><a class="menu_level_1 contact_link" href="contact-us.php#"><i class="fa fa-envelope icon_width"></i>Contact Us<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="container_wrapper" class="scrollable">
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul id="headernav">  
                    <li><a href="index.php#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="location.php#"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i></a></li>  
                    <li><a href="tel:[00353872237667]"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></a></li>  
                    <li><span class="more_button_swipe"><i class="fa fa-navicon"></i></span></li>     
                </ul>               
        </nav>
    </header>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="swipe_sidebar_right"></div>
            <div id="logo_wrapper">
                <img class="logo" src="images/logo-virtu.jpg" height="65" width="150" alt="Logo"/>
                <h2>Contact</h2>
            </div>
            <div id="content">
                <div id="background_grey">  
                    <section id="form_area" class="content_box">
                    </section><!--End of form_area-->
                </div><!--End of background_grey-->
            </div><!--End of content-->
        </div><!--End of container-->   
</body>
```

Comment: here are my 3 images: https://www.funkdafone.com/image_examples/not-working.jpg https://www.funkdafone.com/image_examples/working1.jpg https://www.funkdafone.com/image_examples/working2.jpg

Comment: It's possible JavaScript isn't loaded properly. Any errors on that part perhaps? If so, the issue is "closure" where you should use an [IIFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) instead of globally declared functions. Always refresh using ctrl+f5 to clear the cache which might explain why it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't.

Comment: thanks for your comment.. well I have alerts in my javascript code and they are coming up correctly.. so i think that is loading correctly. and the thing is even if my extra css styling didnt get loaded in the javascript method changeCssOnDocReady() it should still display the page with the basic stylesheet that i load. the fact the body is showing in the right colour (specified in my main stylesheet) would also show that the main stylesheet has loaded. is it possible that the alerts i have would disrupt correct loading? thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have it working now. 
I have decided to change things around so the default css page loaded has the styles necessary for the newer model phones which support overflow:scroll.  So therefore I have set the heights of the body, container_wrappper and side menu to 100% to begin with instead of changing that after receiving a positive response to checking if overflow: scroll is supported...
Instead I check if overflow scroll is not supported and then if not supported i dynamically add a new stylesheet which has the heights of the body and container_wrapper as height: auto; instead of height:100%. it seems that this way around ie changing from height:100% to height: auto displays it correctly as opposed to the way i was doing it starting with no height and adding in height 100% if overflow scroll is* supported.. it was to do with the speed of things loading but when i do it this way even though there is a delay in loading the second stylesheet it still displays correctly after loading.
so i add the following code to my head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main_style_new_phones.css"/>
<script>

if(!canOverflowScroll()){
var lnk=document.createElement('link');
lnk.href='css/main_style_old_phones.css';
lnk.rel='stylesheet';
lnk.type='text/css';
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(lnk);
}
```

and this is the css in main_style_new_phones.css

```
body{
margin-top: 0px;  /*moves #container right up to top of page so no gap*/
font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
width: 100%;
overflow: auto;
z-index: 1;
height: 100%;
}

#container_wrapper{
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 100%;
background: #120F3A;
overflow: auto;
max-width: 100%;  /*same width as full logo image width so that when on full screen the background color of the container doesn't spread across*/ 
z-index: 4;
-webkit-transition: .3s; /* Android 2.1+, Chrome 1-25, iOS 3.2-6.1, Safari 3.2-6  */
-moz-transition: .3s;
-o-transition: .3s;
transition: .3s;  /* Chrome 26, Firefox 16+, iOS 7+, IE 10+, Opera, Safari 6.1+  */
height: 100%;
}
#headernav {  
width: 100%;  
position:fixed;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
z-index: 10;
background: #000;
padding-bottom: 2px;
-webkit-transition: .3s; /* Safari */
transition: .3s;
}
```

and in the css for phones that do not support overflow scroll in main_style_old_phones.css:

```
body{
    height: auto;
    }
    #container_wrapper{
    height: auto;
    }

    #headernav {    
    position:absolute;
    }

    #swipe_menu_right{
    height: auto;
    }
```